# How can we include a user's phone info in the profile?

Tags: feature-request, users

In most questions on AE, one of the more common comments below a question usually are to ask the questioner details regarding his/her device -

- what device are you using?
- what version of Android is your device running?
- Are you rooted?

These questions and the answers to them invariably help a great deal toward answering or focusing a prospective solution to what would be relevant for that particular user.

Is there any way we can set up these fields within a user's profile (with a request to fill in details - not mandatory at all), so it shows below a user's display icon or on hover?

Else can we include a separate field like there is for the tags for a user's device info etc?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/android did something like this, but with CSS files only.  It ended up flopping because Reddit limited the size of the CSS file.  The hovercard was also slightly annoying.

Comment: if this is going to be implemented, don't forget that some people have multiple Android devices and some people switches ROM weekly.

Comment: Odds are that these sort of people are more likely to include their device info in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we discourage phone model tags in non-phone-specific questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions)

Answer (score 6):

We could always make it a convention to include it in the free-form space of our user profiles and suggest others do the same.

Comment: That's what I do, but I often forget to update it when I flash a new ROM.