# Can we add the phone model to the user profile?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we include a user's phone info in the profile?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/how-can-we-include-a-users-phone-info-in-the-profile)

Can we modify the profile data for this site and include a optional phone model?
So that users don't need to repeat the same in every question?